# Proper design for C++ class wrapping multiple possible types

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am trying to implement a C++ class which will wrap a value (among other things). This value may be one of a number of types (string, memory buffer, number, vector).

The easy way to implement this would be to do something like this

```
class A {
    Type type;

    // Only one of these will be valid data; which one will be indicated by `type` (an enum)
    std::wstring wData{};
    long dwData{};
    MemoryBuffer lpData{};
    std::vector<std::wstring> vData{};
};
```

This feels inelegant and like it wastes memory.

I also tried implementing this as a union, but it came with significant development overhead (defining custom destructors/move constructors/copy constructors), and even with all of those, there were still some errors I encountered.

I've also considered making `A` a base class and making a derived class for each possible value it can hold. This also feels like it isn't a great way to solve the problem.

My last approach would be to make each member an `std::optional`, but this still adds some overhead.

Which approach would be the best? Or is there another design that works better than any of these?

Comment: If I make an `A` object and I decide the value it's wrapping will be a `MemoryBuffer`, am I forced to stick with a `MemoryBuffer` for the lifetime of my object? Or are you trying to design something where you can dynamically switch which type is being stored?

Comment: Yes, the type is meant to remain constant

Comment: Depending on how you want to use `A`, you could make `A` a class template with an argument for the contained type or you could use `std::variant`.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't talked about templates in your question then? Also, how custom is the logic you'll be performing for each different type of object stored?

Comment: how are you going to use `A`? what is the common interface an `A` should support independent of what type it actually holds?

Comment: Yes, I want to make a vector of these and be able to use these without being concerned with the type. If I use templates, then I can't treat them all the same. Ideally, I could say `std::vector<A> values = { A{ "hello" }, A{ 4 } }`

Comment: @JamesMcDowell It sounds like the best solution for you is `std::variant`.

Comment: `A` is a wrapper meant to hold a number of possible types. Other modules in my project will use instances of `A` to pass data around and store instances of `A`. Ideally, they should be able to do so without concern for what type `A` is wrapping. `A` also contains a few methods meant to handle parsing of its wrapped value in a generic way

Comment: constructing them is one thing, but how are you going to use them later? What is the point of treating different types the same when you need to inspect its `type` member before you can do anything with it? There are many ways to achieve type erasure, but details depends on details of how you want to use it

Comment: Many portions of my code will use it without needing to check its type before using it since `A` also has methods for providing generic information for its wrapped value. Other portions will need its original value, so just storing the generic information is insufficient. I'd also like it to be an extensible design in case more types are added later

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). It is typesafe, tested and exactly the right thing for a finite number of possible types.
It also gets rid of the type enum.

```
class A {
    std::variant<std::wstring, long, MemoryBuffer, std::vector<std::wstring>> m_data{}; // default initializes the wstring.
public 
    template<class T>
    void set_data(T&& data) {
        m_data = std::forward<T>(data);
    }

    int get_index() { // returns index of type.
        m_data.index();
    }

    long& get_ldata() {
        return std::get<long>(m_data); // throws if long is not the active type
    }

    // and the others, or

    template<class T> 
    T& get_data() { // by type
        return std::get<T>(m_data);
    }

    template<int N>
    auto get_data() { // by index
        return std::get<N>(m_data);
    }
};

// using:
A a;
a.index() == 0; // true
a.set_data(42); 
a.index() == 1; // true
auto l = a.get<long>(); // l is now of type long, has value 42
a.get<long>() = 1;
l = a.get<1>();
```

PS: This example does not even include the coolest (in my opinion) feature of `std::variant`: [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) I am not sure what you want to do with your class, so I cannot create a meaningful example. If you let me know, I will think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want `QVariant` without the rest of Qt, then :)?

As others have mentioned, you could use `std::variant` and put `using MyVariant = std::variant<t1, t2, ...>` in some common header, and then use it everywhere it's called for. This isn't as inelegant as you may think - the specific types to be passed around are only provided in one place. It is the only way to do it without building a metatype machinery that can encapsulate operations on any type of an object.

That's where [`boost::any`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/any.html) comes in: it does precisely that. It wraps concepts, and thus supports any object that implements these concepts. What concepts are required depends on you, but in general you'd want to choose enough of them to make the type usable and useful, yet not too many so as to exclude some types prematurely. It's probably the way to go, you'd have: `using MyVariant = any<construct, _a>;` then (where `construct` is a contract list, an example of which is as an example in [the documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/any.html), and `_a` is a type placeholder from [`boost::type_erasure`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/boost_typeerasure/reference.html#header.boost.type_erasure.placeholder_hpp).

The fundamental difference between `std::variant` and `boost::any` is that `variant` is parametrized on *concrete types*, whereas `any` is parametrized on *contracts that the types are bound to*. Then, any will happily store an arbitrary type that fulfills all of those contracts. The "central location" where you define an alias for the variant type will constantly grow with `variant`, as you need to encapsulate more type. With `any`, the central location will be mostly static, and would change rarely, since changing the contract requirements is likely to require fixes/adaptations to the carried types as well as points of use.